# Error while instantiating agent random error

Tags: scheduled-tasks, urls

I'm using Sitecore 9.3, Suddenly I faced an error that causes the CM server to be down, and I'm not able to access it.

I checked the logs and this is what I found:

```
ERROR  Error while instantiating agent. Definition: <agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.UrlAgent" method="Run" interval="00:15:00" patch:source="ProjectName.Web.config" xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/"><LogActivity>true</LogActivity></agent>
```

This is the OOB Sitecore task, I don't know why this happen, we have many scheduled tasks, but all run as usual and this happened suddenly out of the blue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an agent `UrlAgent`.

You can see its definition in the error:

```
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.UrlAgent" method="Run" interval="00:15:00" patch:source="ProjectName.Web.config"  xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <LogActivity>true</LogActivity>
</agent>
```

It doesn't have any url defined, that's why it cannot instantiate. There should be second parameter in your config:

```
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.UrlAgent" method="Run" interval="00:15:00">
  <param desc="url">https://<hostname>/sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx</param>
  <LogActivity>true</LogActivity>
</agent>
```

Comment: We already have this as a param:
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.UrlAgent" method="Run" interval="00:15:00">
    <param desc="url" role:require="PRD and ContentManagement">
     https://hostname/sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx
    </param>
</agent>

Comment: I need to mention also that this happens inconsistently, it's a random error, but recently it happens a lot.

Comment: In your comment it clearly says that param url is only set while it's `PRD and ContentManagement`. That role require should be moved to `agent` tag. Otherwise it will throw errors in every other environment.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but this happened on the PRD environment too.
However I checked the showconfig.aspx, and I found that the url is not there, so this is the problem, but I have no idea why it's not there, because as per the rule, it should be there.

Comment: Are you sure that "PRD" is "role" Isn't it "env"? Shouldn't it be `env:require="PRD" role:require="ContentManagement"`?

Comment: I think this is the issue yes, thank you a lot, I'll update it.